# The "this" object is empty in pre('save')

Tags: mongoose

As I described in the title when I want to save a new mongoose document the `pre('save')` method fires, but the `this` element in it is an emtpty object.

The test snippet:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password:String
})

schema.pre('save',(next)=>{
    console.log(this)
    next()
})

var model = mongoose.model('Test',schema)

var test = new model({
    password:'testpass'
})

test.save()
```

I cant see the problem with this basic code.

I am using Mongoose v4.5.9.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with your `pre` save method?

Comment: First of all encrypt the password with salt.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For whatever reason your function cannot have the es6 arrow syntax

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    console.log(this)
    next()
})
```

Will work. I currently have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for this, that resolved a find hook problem for me.

Comment: Thank you! I wasted hours on it!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I should have thought about it. Arrow functions "keep" the context (`this`), meaning that in this case, `this` is not the just-saved object, but the Schema instance.

Comment: I wasted hours on this too, thanks man... I research a little on this after verify the solution and I find [this](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/)  and the author mentions that ES6 '() =>'  doesn't modify the 'this' and 'function()' does, for that reason we all had a empty this.

Comment: Could've spent hours on this. Thanks!

Comment: Weird ass mongoose :(

Comment: Crazy weird... I just spent 1hr checking left and right what im doing wrong.

Comment: That's because **arrow function don't get their own `this`** so they get `this` from the outer scope (probably the global object in this case) and **not** what Mongoose is trying to pass (the document).

Comment: Ow w0w, found this after searching for an hour on a solution for this.

Comment: Yes.. right, just forgot this one.. thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The answer from user "unR" is correct. You can not use `this` when you are using an arrow function on a pre save function. You will also find this on all other types of mongoose schema functions. I have expanded on this answer to help clarify why this occurs.

This breaks:

```
schema.pre('save', (next) => { // arrow function
  console.log(this);
  next();
});
```

This works:

```
schema.pre('save', function preSave(next) { // regular function
  console.log(this);
  next();
});
```

The reason:

The problem occurs because of how arrow functions treat "**scope**" differently to regular functions. Arrow functions do not keep scope within the function but rather *forcefully* inherit scope from the outside or surrounding function (this means it will overwrite functions such as `exampleMethod.bind(this)`). In the case above; there is no outside function so the `this` value would be equal to `undefined`.

However, when you use the regular function declaration, the scope can be overwritten by mongoose using the `.bind()` method. As such, they bind the function to the schema object which allows you to have access to the schema properties and functions within the function.

Here is a helpful resource on arrow functions and how they work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: they should really mention this thing in the doc. Thanks